# Hide hour from displaying when using user_registered

Tags: users

`$user->user_registered` displays 
"Registered since: 2014-08-18 07:25:22"

I just want to show the date, not the hour. How can I hide the hour and just show the date?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just show the first 10 characters of the string, like:

```
echo substr($user->user_registered, 0, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) as this would give the ability to format the date:

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$date = new DateTime($user->user_registered);
echo 'Registered since: '.$date->format('jS F Y');
```